# Using Reg Ex in a mySQL update statement

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to change a number of domain names in email addresses in a mySQL table such as

`name@old.domain.co.uk` to something like `name@newdomain.com`

Can I use a Regular Expression to do this in an update statement and if so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no regex replace in MySQL but you can use an UDF (User defined function) like these:

- http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/
- http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Links extracted from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry MySQL regex functionality is limited to just searching, you can't directly replace with it.

Using a UDF to give regex functionality works though, if you want to go that route -

> http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/
>
> https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp